# CSS: small footer problem with big horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I can't get my footer at work. For some reason it gives a scrollbar at 100% width.
I tried to implement the Sticky Footer technique, probb something went wrong :D

This is the css code which controls the footer:

```
.mf{
background: #eaeade;
width: 100%;
padding-left:100px;
padding-top:51px;
padding-bottom:11px;
position: absolute;
margin: 0 auto;
bottom: 0;
}
```

This is the html:

```
<div style="background-color:#EAEADE;text-align:center;overflow:hidden;">
                    <div class='mf'>
              <div class='home-links-footer' style="color:#8E8E80;">
                <a href="index.php">Home</a> | <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=14&Itemid=5">Beveel ons aan!</a> | <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=2">Onze Services</a> | <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5&Itemid=3">Laptop Reparatie</a> | <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=4">Onze Tarieven</a> | <a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=14&Itemid=5">Contact Gegevens</a> | <a href="#">Sitemap</a>
              </div>
              <div style="color:#8E8E80;border-bottom:1px dotted;padding-bottom:3px;width:700px;margin:auto;">
                Friese Computerservice - 8932 JZ Leeuwarden - <a href="mailto:info@friesecomputerservice.nl" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#F57F20;font-weight:bold;">info@friesecomputerservice.nl</span></a> - Tel. 058-8446628 Mob. 06-29594595
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that the CSS box model considers the "width" to mean the width of the **content** of the box, not the overall size of the box. You've given your box padding on the left and right, so that padding is going to be **outside** the 100% width.

Personally I find that an extremely bizarre mechanism to work with, but there you go.

What *should* work (but won't in old IE versions) is to not mention "width" and just set "left" and "right" to 0.

Comment: my bad, I had to change position to relative

Comment: Forget to respond on the first lines of your answer, I didn't knew this. Thank you!